# Spark Kubernetes Error: Pod already Exists error

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform

```
Exception in thread "main" io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods. Message: pods "livy-session-71-aa59b084378baed1-driver" already exists. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=409, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null, kind=pods, name=livy-session-71-aa59b084378baed1-driver, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=pods "livy-session-71-aa59b084378baed1-driver" already exists, metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=AlreadyExists, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:568)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.assertResponseCode(OperationSupport.java:507)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:471)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:430)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleCreate(OperationSupport.java:251)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:815)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:333)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client.$anonfun$run$2(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client.$anonfun$run$2$adapted(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2539)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.$anonfun$run$4(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.$anonfun$run$4$adapted(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2539)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.start(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I am trying to run a spark submit command and i am getting the above error.

I am using zeppelin livy interpreter to submit spark commands to a k8 cluster.
There aren't any pods with the same name in the cluster.